# Как обойти список системных процессов?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Список процессов которые нужно обойти в цикле

```
var name = new List<string>
{
   "svchost", "csrss", "System", "wininit"
}
```

Пробую так:

```
var etc = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var anti in etc)
{
  foreach (var s in name)
  {
     if (name.IndexOf(anti.ProcessName.ToLower()) < 0)
     {
         anti.Kill();
     }
  }
}
```

---

Но выходит исключение:

Необработанное исключение типа `"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception" в System.dll`

---

Что нужно исправить?

Comment: может это имелось введу s.IndexOf(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
var names = new List<string> { "svchost", "csrss", "System", "wininit" };
var processes = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (var process in processes)
{
    if (!names.Contains(process.ProcessName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
}
```

PS: давайте нормальные имена вашим переменным. Все эти `etc`, `anti`, `s` - сами в них не путаетесь? Также учитывайте число: имён в коллекции подразумевается несколько, поэтому название должно быть `names`, а не `name` (даже если коллекция пустая).

Comment: Но тогда мой процесс закрывается

Comment: Попробовал добавить строку: `if (!names.Contains(process.ProcessName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && process.ProcessName != currentProcess.ProcessName)` щас всё работает.

Comment: @ArteS - проще добавить свой процесс в список `names`.

Comment: Это да) Но вот если процесс переименовывается, что тогда делать))

Comment: Интересный способ, а если список не в `List<string>` а просто в `new string[] {"", ""}` ?? Я попробовал, но список не обходит процессов. Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Цикл `foreach (var s in name)` лишний, из за него Вы каждый процесс пытаетесь убыть 4 раза (столько элементов в списке):

```
var etc = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var anti in etc)
{
    if (name.IndexOf(anti.ProcessName.ToLower()) < 0)
    {
        anti.Kill();
    }
}
```

Comment: Процессы обходит, вот только не убиваются остальные процессы ( которых нет в списке ).

Comment: Не все процессы можно убывать. Вы же убьете свой процесс тоже.

Comment: Даже свой не убивается. По сути должно так работать, все процессы которые есть в списке `List` не трогать их, остальные которые есть в диспетчере должны закрыться! Но ни один не закрывается.

Comment: Потому, что в начале попадается процесс, которого нельзя убить. В моем случае на первом же процессе: `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied'
`. А зачем убивать все процессы?

Comment: Там список нужно дополнять в `List<string>` системных, по сути краша не должно быть. Зачем убивать все процессы? ( это такая система защита от всякой грязи, типо вирусов))

Comment: Попробуйте `anti.Kill();` вставить в `try catch`, в таком случае он при ошибке продолжит дальше.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60995/discussion-between-artes-and-koshe).